# Menu horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to make a menu that can be horizontally scrolled.
I have found several examples.

I really like [this](https://benfrain.com/a-horizontal-scrolling-navigation-pattern-for-touch-and-mouse-with-moving-current-indicator/), but it looks very complicated.
This is also good: [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp). It is simpler.

I do not know how to integrate.

My menu: twig (template engine)

```
{% for title,item in items %}
 {% if item is not iterable %}
 <li>
 <a href="{{ item }}">{{ title }}</a>
 </li>
 {% else %}
 <li><a class="dropdown">{{ title }}</a>
 <ul>
 {% include "menu_links.twig" with {'items': item} %}
 </ul>
 </li>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I integrate?

Comment: If you have a nav with a fixed width > window size, just add overflow-x: auto; or scroll; to the nav.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.
But, I need something like this. Including a clickable arrow. 
https://benfrain.com/a-horizontal-scrolling-navigation-pattern-for-touch-and-mouse-with-moving-current-indicator/

Comment: Nice, what have you tried? Please include a full js fiddle example. Perhaps not with twig.